# Please suggest regarding this exception in Android, How to fix this issue

Tags: android

I had a log which looks like this, what is the cause and how i can solve this problem please suggest

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(SourceFile:1343)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(SourceFile:1354)
           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(SourceFile:595)
           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(SourceFile:574)
           at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(SourceFile:189)
           at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(SourceFile:155)
           at com.replicon.cloudclock.timeoff.view.TimeOffActivity$5.run(SourceFile:1264)
           at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

thse code snippet is shown here where i had the problem

```
final Timer dismissTimeOut = new Timer();
        dismissTimeOut.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timeOffDialogFragment.dismiss(); 
                dismissTimeOut.cancel(); 

            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: please show some code and where you are getting the exception

Comment: Haven't tried myself but: 1) cancel your timer e.g. in activity `onPause()`- though the order of `onPause()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` is not defined. 2) In timer callback, use `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `dismiss()`

Comment: @lalto many thanks i will do the same and will check!!

Answer (score 1):

Try `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `commit()`.
Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss).

[Source](https://groups.google.com/group/androiddevelopers/browse_thread/thread/74eacf9d7a32f8d3).

Comment: The commit() is not in his code but in support lib. There's `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` though.

Comment: The second link is dead : "The requested topic cannot be found. It might have been deleted."

Comment: @laalto can you help me on this issue?